# io.read in Lua doesn't work

Tags: lua

When this function is executed, only the second io.read is being shown, the first is just ignored:

```
function playernames ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("\n Player 1, choose a name: ")
    playername1 = io.read ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("\n Player 2, choose a name: ")
    playername2 = io.read ()
end
```

How do I show the first `io.read` properly?

Comment: What do you mean by the first is ignored? Did you print the value of `playername1`?

Comment: There is no possibility to fill in the value for playername1, it just skips it and lets you fill in the value for playername2.

Comment: print the value of `playername1` right after `playername1 = io.read ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know the least bit about Lua, so it's a wild guess, but shouldn't that be:

```
function playernames ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("Player 1, choose a name: ")
    playername1 = io.read ()
    io.write ("\n")
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("Player 2, choose a name: ")
    playername2 = io.read ()
    io.write ("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well "cls" is going to clear the screen so if you want both still on the screen after typing them you need to remove the second "cls":

```
function playernames ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("\n Player 1, choose a name: ")
    playername1 = io.read ()
    io.write ("\n Player 2, choose a name: ")
    playername2 = io.read ()
end

playernames ()
```

If you simply want to show them then:

```
function playernames ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("\n Player 1, choose a name: ")
    playername1 = io.read ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("\n Player 2, choose a name: ")
    playername2 = io.read ()
    os.execute ("cls")
    io.write ("Player 1: "..playername1.."\n") --or use print here
    io.write ("Player 2: "..playername2.."\n")
end

playernames ()
```

Else if this is not the answer you were looking for you should specify
"How do I show the first io.read properly?".